# Error running VS2013 Express project executable file

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, executable, directx-11

I'm trying to run a VS2013 Express executable file that is created when building my project and is located in the Debug directory of that project.

When trying to run the .exe file this message is displayed:

`"This application failed to start because D3DCompiler_47.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem."`

So I downloaded the dll and pasted it into the Debug folder together with the .exe file. When I try to run it gives me:

`The application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b`

I've searched for solutions but there a lot of methods that requires me to download files from shady sites.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a `DirectX` related problem as discussed in this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Depending on your Windows version, the `DirectX DLLs` are installed in different fashions. Make sure that `DirectX` installation is working OK and using DLLs for the proper `CPU` type (32-bit vs. 64-bit).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I performed steps 5a-5e as well as 6a-6c since they seemed to be most relevant for my problems.  Now a x64 directory appears in my solution folder with sub folders for Debug and Relase with each an executable within.

I don't get the error message anymore but now the application window open and closes immediately. Now my hlsl-files fails to compile with the message that it cannot find the given entrypoint. I've always had all shaders in one effect in the same file. Does this mean I have to split them up? Also now it complains on semantics which does'nt make sense at all :(

Comment: Sorry, but I can only guess here. Have you tried to clean and rebuild the project/solution? It might even be necessary (or easier than a manual repair) to re-create the whole solution.

Comment: I managed to get the executable working by re-creating the project. This time however I created a Win32 Console Application instead of an Empty Project as I've always done before.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you running?

`D3DCompiler_47.dll` is built into the Window 8.1 and Windows 10 OS. You can also find a copy in the Windows 8.1 SDK under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Redist\D3D` for use with Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8.0.

See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)

Comment: As of today I'm a proud owner of Windows 10. I managed to get the executable working by simply creating a new project and paste the code into that. This time however I created a Win32 Console Application instead of an Empty Project as I've always done before.